# How to allow upload file name with special characters in YII?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, yii, filenames

I want to upload the file with name containing special characters(like @,#,!,~ etc). How can i allow the file names with these characters. My code is:

```
public function actionAddImage()
{           

    $model=new Gallery;
    $this->pageTitle = CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name).' :: Add Image';

    if(isset($_POST['Gallery']))
    {
        $rnd = rand(0,9999);
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Gallery'];
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$uploadedFile}";

        $model->image = $fileName;
        $model->description = $_POST['Gallery']['description'];

        if($model->save())
        {               
             $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$fileName); // image will uplode to rootDirectory/banner/

             //thumbmail---------------start---
            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/original/');             
            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$fileName)->resize(538,359)->save($fileName);

            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/thumb/');                
            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$fileName)->resize('0','110')->save($fileName);   

            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/thumb_70/');
            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$fileName)->resize('0',70)->save($fileName);  

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('employee','Image has been added successfully');
            $this->redirect(array('ManageGalleries'));
        }
    }
    $this->layout = "loginMain";
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

when i tried to upload the file with name containing special characters its not uploading the file.
Please help me how can allow this to file names.

Comment: I don't think this is limitation of yii, more likely it's browser / http / os limitation. I don't think there is a way around this (except to remove all such characters from file name).

Comment: Support for special characters in filenames varies between operating systems, and PHP itself has issues with them as well. Sanitize the actual filename, if you must keep the original filename, save it in the database.